# Disable environment contents

Tags: environments

I want to prevent the content of a custom environment from being shown. I've tried:

```
\newenvironment{asdf}[3]
{
  %some stuff happens here
  %......
  \begin{comment}
}{
   \end{comment}
}
```

but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}`, use `\comment` and `\endcomment`.  The reason for this is that the `\comment` command proceeds by searching the text for the beginning of `\end{<envname>}`, where `<envname>` is the name of the environment it was called from.

This allows you to call comments from your own environments: `\comment` will see the end of your environment and know that the extent of the commenting has come to an end.  With the code you gave, it would be looking for `\end{comment}`, never find it since it will never expand `\end{asdf}`, and continue forever.

(Oddly, this means that you *must* comment within a LaTeX environment: the pair of commands `\comment`/`\endcomment`, written directly into your document, will not work, unlike every other environment!  But verbatim text, of which commenting is an example, is very odd all around.)

Comment: This produces an error: ! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.50 \end{frame}

Comment: Found it: I was using \usepackage{comment} instead of \usepackage{verbatim}. Thanks for your help!