# Disable environment contents by condition

Tags: environments, comments

I have implemented another [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6597/disable-environment-contents)'s accepted answer in an attempt to omit any contents of my custom environment if an optional argument is specified. However, even the most basic version does not compile. The answer has plenty of upvotes, so people seem to have found it helpful.

What am I missing? Oddly enough, it does compile if the condition (now omitted from the example) is not met and `\comment` is never called.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\newenvironment{myenv}{\comment}{\endcomment}

\begin{document}
    \begin{myenv}
        This is text.
    \end{myenv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your document doesn't compile because `document` has nothing. Try adding another line of text, and it will compile.

Comment: @JouleV Right. That's.. unexpected. Well, thanks!